Emmet functionality Not working In VS Code using .Jsx file
I tried searching and going through some issues opened by others on GitHub but none worked for me.
So what's the problem:
I am attaching ss :


After that when I hit enter nothing happened before a space was generated where I write the tag name: div, p, span
this is the configuration of emmet in my VS

I also tried the same method in which we save the file and then try. No result.
So, after trying different methods nothing works now.. though it was working before and I don't remember when.
EDIT: it's not working in Home.jsx but working fine in other components
